# Yup InferType for array of strings not working as expected

Tags: typescript, type-inference, yup

I'm trying to use Yup to define a schema and generate a Typescript Type that I can use for my objects.

Using InferType seems to work fine for strings and objects, but there's unexpected behavior for arrays. When `required()` or `defined()` is used with `of()`, the types stop working as I would expect.

*NOTE: the validation functionality is working fine; I'm only having trouble with InferType*

## Ideal: InferType combines all operations to the expected type `string[]`

```
const schema = yup.array().required().of(yup.string().required());
type SchemaType = yup.InferType<typeof schema>;

// Type should be `string[]`
const schemaInstance: SchemaType = ["string1"];
```

## Actual Scenario 1: array is `string[] | undefined`

```
const schema = yup.array().required().of(yup.string().required());
type SchemaType = yup.InferType<typeof schema>;

// Type is `string[] | undefined` so the following line compiles
const schemaInstance: SchemaType = undefined;
```

## Actual Scenario 2: array is `any`

```
const schema = yup.array().of(yup.string().required()).required();
type SchemaType = yup.InferType<typeof schema>;

// Type is `any` so the following line compiles
const schemaInstance: SchemaType = {};
```

---

Is there a way to make these types work as expected for an array of strings?

Comment: Share reproducable example

Comment: @captain-yossarian The above scenarios are reproducible by importing yup and inspecting the types. Scenario 1 would and Scenario 2 would _ideally_ have type `string[]` but instead have the listed types, reducing type-safety.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
const schema = yup.array().of(yup.string().required()).required();
type SchemaType = yup.InferType<typeof schema>;
```

It should work now, your error has been fixed.